# writeDate Macro not working in version 7.6.4 rev2 after years of using it

Tags: windows-10, date, libreoffice-base, imacros

I have been using this macro for years to assign todays date as the default date to a field
when no date is selected.  I downloaded version 7.6.4 rev2 and it stopped working.

REM This macro writes the date of today to the Date Field myDateField

```
Sub writeDate

Dim today As New com.sun.star.util.Date

today.Month = Month( Now )

today.Day = Day( Now )

today.Year = Year( Now )

form = ThisComponent.DrawPage.Forms(0)  ' first form

form.datReceivedDate.BoundField.UpdateDate( today )

End Sub
```

Error on this line  form = ThisComponent.DrawPage.Forms(0)  ' first form

Basic runtime error. Property or method not found DrawPage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which editor is this? What is your operating system?

Comment: LibreOfficeBase portable in Windows 10 OS

Comment: I have a form in LibreOfficeBase that accepts a date field.  When no date is selected manually I want Todays Date in the field.  When I updated to the ne version of LibreOffice the macro I have been using for years suddenly stopped working.